# How to store RDF data direct to sesame using D2R?

Tags: sesame, triplestore

I am looking for any solution, to store my RDFized data direct to sesame through Java program. I have a database of 1.7 M records, i used D2R to transform it into RDF. Now i want to store RDFized data into sesame triple store. I did not generate RDF dump because data was huge. Is there any way code/solution through which i can shift my RDFized data into my triple store. Thanks

Comment: There are probably several ways to achieve this. But you'll have to be a bit more specific about your setup and what exactly you're looking for. You say you don't have an RDF dump, yet you also say you generated RDF using D2R. So what _do_ you have?

Comment: You might also show what you've tried.  There are plenty of examples of how to use the Sesame API available online which you could adapt to loading a live feed or a file dump.

Comment: Thanks Jeen and Michael for reply. Well, i was asking, I have rdfized data with D2R which is accessible at.(http://cbakerlab.unbsj.ca:8080/liapibackup/snorql/). The issue is SPARQL query execution time is very slow due to mysql database at back end. Someone suggested me, if i store the data into sesame it can enhance the accessing speed. I searched on internet to find a tutorial which can guide me do this but could not find any. Please share with me any example/tutorial if you know. Thanks.

Comment: I'd say, have a look at the Sesame website at http://www.openrdf.org/ . Click on "Documentation", then on "User documentation", which takes you to the Sesame user documentation, which contains a section on how to program with Sesame. Have a browse through there and try some stuff out. You will also find the API javadoc there somewhere. If you get stuck, feel free to ask here or on the Sesame mailinglist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you're really trying to say is:
you have a large RDBMS over which you've created an RDF wrapper view using D2RQ. 
Now you want to extract that data using SNORQL (D2RQ's SPARQL endpoint) and push it to a native RDF triple store using Sesame.

I tried to edit your question to reflect that but unfortunately it got voted down.

Anyway, in Sesame, you can do this through Java code by:

1. firing a Graph Query that will return you a GraphQueryResult

   ```
   GraphQueryResult graphResult = con.prepareGraphQuery(
   QueryLanguage.SPARQL, "CONSTRUCT <...your SPARQL QUERY here ...>".evaluate();
   ```
2. use the QueryResults utility class to return the Statements as a Model:

   ```
   Model resultModel = QueryResults.asModel(graphQueryResult);
   ```
3. use one of the overloaded RepositoryConnection.add methods to add this data to a native Sesame store.

Comment: Good, but you can actually skip step 2 entirely. A `GraphQueryResult` is a subtype of `Iteration`, so you can feed it directly into the `RepositoryConnection.add` method. This has the advantage that the result does not have to be fully materialized in a Model first: it can be processed in a streaming fashion.